# How to determine the extreme of a peak vs. the average when the average is negative?

Tags: statistics

I'm sorry this is a dumb question but i am looking for a way to gauge how "extreme" a value is compared to the average of a set of data. When the average is positive the math is fine. ie. the "peak" is 8, and the average is 4, the peak is 100% higher than the average. But when the average is negative, let's say -4, how would i do that?

Comment: It's a problematic measure,  If the average is $0$ then a score of $1$ is infinitely above the average in percentage terms.    In such cases, additive differences are more meaningful.

Comment: @lulu the problem when i use additive differences is that when the data has larger more extreme values it will make the relative difference look larger, that's why i want to use something uniform. Is standard deviation what i'm looking for?

Comment: Standard deviation was made to gauge how extreme values were, so I would definitely go for that.

Comment: You might try making a _boxplot,_ embellished to identify _outliers._ Roughly an outlier is a value that is 'far away' from the main body of the data. Google or check an elementary statistics textbook.

Comment: Standard deviation is a different sort of measure.  It tells you how often the observation is meant to be some distance from the mean.  Very useful of course, but it's not the same as simply identifying the peaks.  It all depends on how you intend to use the measure.  You could, for example, just take the first decile ($10\%$ of your observations are above $X$ or whatever).

Comment: @lulu i'm writing a program and i'm cycling through a set of variables to do calculations on my data. I want the set of variables where the peak of the data is the most extreme relative to the data as a whole. In this case, there is only one peak that i'm trying to isolate.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but don't you then just want the maxima?  Or, like I say the top decile or something like that?

Comment: @lulu i don't really care about the value itself, i just want it to be the most extreme compared to the data as a whole.

Comment: How does that differ from extreme values?  I think I am missing your point.  If I take the biggest $10%$ of the values then, a fortiori, I am getting those that differ most from the mean.

Comment: Let's say for example i have a set of data that is very scattered i could have a bunch of secondary peaks at a slightly lower values than the absolute peak. However i could have another set of data that is less scattered and the other peaks could be far below the absolute peak making it a more "extreme" peak, while still having the same peak value and mean value.

Answer (score 0):

I will illustrate some two 'descriptive methods' of data analysis used to identify 'extreme observations'. I will illustrate them in terms of two samples, each of size 20.

**A normal sample.**

```
X:
 7.67  8.11  8.52  8.72  8.72  8.99  9.02  9.47  9.54 10.14
10.21 10.24 10.25 10.41 10.86 10.87 10.87 10.94 11.06 11.25
```

Here the sample mean is $\bar X = 9.79$ and the sample standard deviation
is $S_x = 1.08.$  These data are from a normally distribution.
For a small normal sample, it is typical for all or most of
the observations to be within two standard deviations of the mean $\bar X \pm 2S_x.$ For this sample, that interval is $(7.63, 11.96).$ Above, the
data have been sorted from smallest to largest, so it is easy to see that
all 20 of our observations are within the interval.

A boxplot is based on the minimum, lower quartile, median, upper quartile, and maximum ('five-number summary') of the data. For our sample these numbers are:

```
 Min    Q1    Median Q3     Max
 7.670  8.855 10.175 10.865 11.250
```

Here is the boxplot. The ends of the 'box' are at the quartiles $Q_1$ and $Q_2$
the ends of the 'whiskers' are at the Min and Max.

[image]

The 'interquartile range' IQR $=Q_2 - Q_1 = 1.94.$ If any data point were
below $Q_1 - 1.5\text{IQR}$ or above $Q_3 + 1.5\text{IQR},$ then it would
be called an 'outlier' and plotted as a separate dot. But there are no
outliers in this sample.

**An exponential sample.**

By contrast, here is a second sample. This one is from an exponential
distribution. It is typical for exponential data to have some extreme values
on the high side.

```
Y:
 0.9  1.4  3.2  4.5  4.5  5.2  5.4  6.4  7.0  8.0
10.5 10.5 11.3 16.0 16.7 16.7 18.6 25.0 25.2 35.6
```

For these data $\bar Y = 11.63,\, S_y = 9.16$ and the five-number summary is:

```
  Min   Q1    Med  Q3    Max
  0.90  4.85  9.25 16.70 35.60
```

The interval $\bar Y \pm 2S_y$ is $(-6.69, 29.95),$ which includes all of
the data except for 35.6. Notice that $S_y$ is very large; the extreme high
observations have inflated the sample standard deviation so that this
interval includes the large observations in the 20's.

A boxplot of these data identifies the maximum observation 35.6 as an
outlier, plotting it as a separate dot beyond the end of the right-hand whisker.
In this sample $Q_3 + 1.5IQR = 34.21 < 35.6.$

[image]

**Summary.** I have illustrated two possible methods of identifying 'extreme'
observations: (1) Falling outside the interval that extends two standard deviations on either side of the sample mean, (2) Identified as a boxplot
outlier according to the 1.5IQR rule.

It turned out that neither method found an extreme observation in the normal
data (X) and that both methods found an extreme observation in the exponential data (Y). However, the two methods are based on different criteria for what
is 'extreme' and they do not always give the same result.

It is important to know about extreme observations or 'outliers' in a dataset.
You might want to check whether an extreme observation resulted from a mistake
(incorrect measurement, data entry error, etc.) and should be corrected or
eliminated from the dataset.

However, extreme observations are sometimes
important reminders that the data are not always as expected. Sometimes outliers just happen at random, somtimes they are a usual feature of the distribution involved, and somtimes they are 'newsworthy' warnings of unusual events.

Outliers are surprisingly common even when nothing is 'wrong': Moderately large normal
samples frequently have a few outliers. Even small exponential samples usually have at least one outlier. The figure below shows 20 boxplots from each type of distribution, plotted vertically.

[image]

*Note:* Whether data are positive or negative is not a major issue in
identifying extreme values. Both of the methods discussed here work whether
nor not there are negative observations in the data.